# What is your feedback on the attached screenshot?

Tags: messages, onboarding, tutorial

[image: Tutorial 1]

This is a Tutorial screen which shows up to a first time user to help them understand the process. Can you please help us with your feedback?

Comment: What's a "source stop"? Is it where you get on?

Comment: yes.. Your start point. I know the communication part is little verbose. you can suggest better text as well.

Comment: How about "embarkation point"?

Comment: What is the ux question?

Comment: @mayo, I don't want to confine the scope of UX by putting up a specific question here. It was an attempt to understand all the possible ways of looking at it and enhancing the user experience. If you can see  below Sagar has pointed out a very interesting fact that the actions here are not clear and it may confuse users.

Answer (score 2):

- Many steps informed in a single sentence
- 'Close' cross image should be right hand, isn't it?
- It is not clear, whether you want user to click on that orange 'Edit' button or 'Next' arrow (which seems obvious in such screens)?

Comment: Why do you feel that cross button should be on right? will it give you more convenience to use it. Cross icon will skip the process and I don't want users to skip.

Comment: oh yes..we are used to have CLOSE button on right side (at least where i live). 'Back' button on left and 'Close' on right, thats what we are used to.

Comment: don't you think it's a web kind of style to have cross on right. In mobile apps, most of the times they have done on right and back & close on left.